# splitting a reward across different users based on linked variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, better-sqlite3

Say I have user 1, user 2, and user 3. user 1 has 10x user 2 has 50x and user 3 has 40x. There is a reward and the reward is 1y. How is it possible to split that reward accordingly to the variables tied to each user? The user data is stored in a sqlite db.

Comment: You mean dividing y to 100x and give them each 10%, 50% and 40%?

Comment: yes, that is what I want but I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const users = [
  {name: 'user 1', weight: 10},
  {name: 'user 2', weight: 50},
  {name: 'user 3', weight: 40}
]
const reward = 200

const totalWeight = users.reduce((total, {weight}) => total += weight, 0)
const splitReward = users.reduce((obj, {name, weight}) => {
  obj[name] = reward * weight / totalWeight
  return obj
}, {})
console.log(splitReward)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation so I am posting it as answer

As per your statement,

```
100x of reward = 1y;
```

So the reward for a user with 1x is,

```
1x of reward = 1y / 100;
```

For example, if a user gets 40x reward, then

```
40x reward = 1y / 100 * 40
```

You can calculate the reward for any multiplier of x like this

```
(reward_multiplier)x reward = 1y / 100 * (reward_multiplier)
```